# Hyper-v and VirtualBox conflict in Dockers with Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, hyper-v, minikube

I'm trying to scale my docker containers with Minikube on Windows 10 Enterprise Edition. However, I'm running into a few conflicts with Hyper-V and VirtualBox. I know Dockers require Hyper-V to run properly while Minikube requires VirtualBox to run (shows an error if Hyper-V is enabled)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
160.27 MB / 160.27 MB [============================================] 100.00% 
0s
E0822 11:42:07.898412   13028 start.go:174] Error starting host: Error 
creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when 
Hyper-V is activated. Either use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V 
hypervisor. (To skip this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check).
```

If I disable, Hyper-V, I'm able to start minikube properly but Dockers does not work and shows an error to enable Hyper-V.

I also tried running minikube with Hyper-V driver, but also get this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --vm-driver hyperv
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0822 11:44:32.323877   13120 start.go:174] Error starting host: Error 
creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this 
command to run. Check https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/.
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also tried running minikube with Hyper-V driver, but also get this error:

There is an explicit warning about that HyperV and vswitch situation in their docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/v0.28.2/docs/drivers.md#hyperv-driver

Although in `minikube`'s defense, it also does say **right at the end** the URL one should go to in order to read about the `--hyperv-virtual-switch` flag one should provide in addition to `--vm-driver=hyperv`.

Navigating to that linked docker page, it even provides a step-by-step with screenshots example of how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Next steps solved my problem:

```
> minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv -v 9999
```

If there is another error such

> Error: [HYPERV_NO_VSWITCH] create: precreate: no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this command to run

Just create a switch manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and next command resolve the problem:

```
minikube delete
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

make sure docker is running

open Hyper-V Manager

go to Hyper Switch Manager

create a new virtual switch for internal use

name it for example switch01 then press apply or ok

[image]

then execute the following commands in cmd or power shell

> minikube delete

> minikube start --hyperv-virtual-switch=switch01

> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch switch01 default